# Extrude shadow volumes to infinity

Tags: opengl, shadow, infinity

I want to use the depth-fail algorithm to make shadow volumes and all works great, but i can't figure out how to extrude the shadow volume quads to infinity.

The aim is to create the shadow volume for a triangle that is lit up from a point light. I have red that i first have to change the perspective matrix that it has no far clip pane and set the w coordinate to 0. But what are the x,y,z coordinates then?

An example would be very helpful, but i also want to understand how its done.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why you want to extrude shadow volumes to infinity.

Comment: Tod avoid bugs in the shadow. It is a method that is often used in the depth-fail algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/appendixf.html) shows an example of a projection matrix. It has the form:

```
    a   0   b              0
A = 0   d   e              0
    0   0   -(f+n)/(f-n)   -2fn/(f-n)
    0   0   -1             0
```

`f` is the far plane and you want `f -> infinity`.

```
limit f -> infinity of (f+n)/(f-n) = limit f -> infinity of (1+n/f)/(1-n/f)
```

and

```
limit f -> infinity of 2fn/(f-n) = limit f -> infinity of 2n/(1-n/f)
```

since

```
f -> infinity => n/f -> 0
```

your matrix with `f -> infinity` becomes

```
    a   0   b    0
B = 0   d   e    0
    0   0   -1   -2n
    0   0   -1   0
```

if you transform your (`x,y,z,w=0`) with `B` you'll get

```
x' = ax + bz
y' = dy + ez
z' = -z
w' = -z
```

and the perspective division gives

```
x' = -ax/z - b
y' = -dy/z - e
z' = 1
```

While `x'` and `y'` are the same as transforming (`x,y,z,w=0`) with `A`, `z'` is now a constant that is always equal to the far plane in normalized device coordinates.

This [article](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch09.html) shows an efficient implementation of shadow volumes with capping at infinity.